# Environment variable for command called via nice

Tags: shell, environment-variables, nice

I need to set an environment variable for a command that is being called via nice.  [Bash and dash, Slackware and FreeBSD.]

```
 $ JIM=20 nice -n 10 echo $JIM

 $
```

Nope, `echo` can't see JIM

```
 $ nice -n 10 JIM=20 echo $JIM
 nice: JIM=20: No such file or directory
 $
```

`nice` don't like it.

I can export JIM and then echo can see it, but now I'm polluting the environment.  Unclean!

I tried the "--" option to signify end of command line variables for `nice`, but it makes no difference, `nice` complains.  I can't believe no one has wanted to do this before, so I'm probably making a very basic error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

```
JIM=x
JIM=20 nice -n 10 echo $JIM
```

does pass the `JIM=20` environment variable to `nice`, but it's not `nice` nor `echo` that expands `$JIM`, that's the shell.

The shell forks a process and executes:

```
execve("/usr/bin/nice", ["nice", "-n", "10", "echo", "x"], ["JIM=20", other vars])
```

`nice` sets the niceness and then executes in the same process:

```
execve("/bin/echo", ["echo", "x"], ["JIM=20", other vars])
```

So `echo` does receive `JIM=20` in its environment, but `echo` doesn't do anything with its environment.

Had you run:

```
JIM=20 nice -n 10 sh -c 'echo $JIM'
```

Then `sh` would have done something with that environment variable. Shells map the environment variables they receive to shell variables. So above, that `sh` would have set its `$JIM` variable to `20` and called its `echo` builtin with `20` as argument.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
( export a=20; nice -n 10 sh -c 'echo $a' )
```

Comment: This expands the variable in the argument list (which is what the OP's example tries to do), but **it doesn't pass it in the environment** (which is what the question asks for.)

Answer (score 0):

For my particular case, I ended up making the script renice itself, similar to this:

```
JIM=20 sh -c 'renice -n +15 -p $$; echo ${JIM}'
```